# Homework Palindrome.java (Introduce?)

Tags: java, netbeans

Objective: (Palindrome integer) Write the methods with the following headers:

```
// Return the reversal of an integer, i.e., reverse(456) returns 654 public static int reverse(int number)

// Return true if number is a palindrome public static boolean isPalindrome(int number)
```

Use the reverse method to implement isPalindrome. A number is a palindrome if its reversal is the same as itself. Write a test program that prompts the user to enter an integer and reports whether the integer is a palindrome.

**My question is after the code below**

```
public class NewClass {

    public static int reverse(int number) {
        int reverse = 0;
        while (number != 0) {
            reverse = (reverse * 10) + number % 10;
            number = number / 10;
        }
        return (reverse);
    }

    public static boolean isPalindrome(int number) {
        return (number == reverse(number));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
        java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
        int number = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Reversed: " + reverse(number));

        if (number == reverse(number)) {
            System.out.println(number + " is a palindrome.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("It is not a palindrome.");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm having issues with this line:

```
   public static boolean isPalindrome(int number) {
       return (number == reverse(number));
```

NetBeans keeps telling me to `introduce` it but I don't know what that means. The code created (from the help of many others already) has an error because I've not `introduced` the above code. I'm at wits and tired. I've been at this since 5pm and only came here but an hour ago. I need an explanation. **Question: I'd rather not alter was below but I don't know what to do with that specific line! If you don't want to help, don't comment.**

Comment: Can you please share the exact text of the error you're getting?

Comment: You should read [FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites)

Comment: You're naming the parameter "reverse" same as the method name...

Comment: Warning? It's the only thing preventing me from uploading the code to a very particular program: "LiveLab"

Comment: @ alfasin Could you please elaborate for me. I'm only 2 months in and this has been nothing but confusing.

Comment: Could someone explain what alfasin stated or give a non-related example at least, rather than just vote down...

Comment: ...is there a more responsive forum or chat lounge I can join? I need help. There's plenty people on here but no one responding...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You never call this method.

Change:

```
   if (number == reverse(number)) {
        System.out.println(number + " is a palindrome.");
    }
     else{
       System.out.println("It is not a palindrome.");        
    }
```

To

```
  if (isPalindrome(number)) {
        System.out.println(number + " is a palindrome.");
    }
     else{
       System.out.println("It is not a palindrome.");        
    }
```

And the error should be gone.

Comment: Out of interest what is the netbeans error in question here? Eclipse would just report method not referenced... actually it wouldn't because it's public...

Comment: OHHHHhhhh... `introduce`.

Comment: `Introduce...`  It's one of the light bulbs on the numbered lines. I deleted the class then started fresh. It has gone away BUT I understand the introduce portion now. Thank you.